# How to display the number of lines output by a command in real time?

Tags: shell, pipe, progress-information

I'm using `svn export` as part of a packager script for my application, and it looks like this command, like many others, doesn't have any kind of progress bar.

I have two choices at the moment:

- using it without options, and watch it printing thousands of lines
- using `--quiet`, and not seing anything until it completes.

Is there a way to at least show the number of lines output by the command, in real time? Such as:

```
Exporting SVN directory ... 1234 files
```

And see this number `1234` **increment in real time**? I can imagine piping the output to a command that would do just this, but which one?

Answer (score 22):

```
yourcommand | { I=0; while read; do printf "$((++I))\r"; done; echo ""; }
```

Or put the bracketed section in a shell script.  Note that this only works if your shell actually supports the preincrement operator, like bash or ksh93 or zsh.  Otherwise you'll have to increment `$I` and then print it (as in `I=$((I+1));printf...`).  Also, if `printf` isn't a builtin with your shell (it's a builtin with current bash), you could use `echo -ne` or `print -n` instead for better performance.  You just want to suppress the newline and have the \r interpreted as an escape character.

Comment: Oh, I'll never make myself learn bashscripting with all its ugly `=` and ` = ` differences and quirks. :) Why wouldn't they replace it with python-like-syntaxed language...

Comment: Hey, I know, what! You can add carriage return symbol to each new line you print, and it won't flood the screen, it will just overwrite the previous line.

Comment: That's why the `printf` ends with a `\r`.  And what happens if you do `echo -ne "$I\r"` or `print -n "$I\r"`. :)  I used `printf`, however, because it defaults to not printing a newline at the end, so the `\r` just moves back to the beginning.  Not all echo implementations support the `-e` or `-n` argument, unfortunately.

Comment: This also works with the pdksh version that OpenBSD uses for /bin/sh.

Comment: For the rest of this, putting a series of commands inside `{}` groups them together like an inline function.  `$(())`` does math expansion.  And the rest is just a standard shell while loop.  I guess it's worth noting that `read` takes one line from STDIN, storing it in `$REPLY` if no other var is specified.  Since the whole thing is in `{}`, `read`'s stdin is connected to the output of the pipeline.  So the contents of the loop happen once per line.  Then there's a plain `echo` at the end to print a newline when it's done reading (when SDIN closes).

Comment: hm, but on my Debian 7 `echo -ne "\r"` doesn't erase the line for some reason

Comment: The `\r` just moves the cursor to the beginning of the line.  Erasing would be done by printing a carriage return, printing spaces over the whole line, then printing another carriage return.  Does that help?

Comment: In this specific case, because the number is constantly incrementing, the newly printed number will always be as long or one character longer than what was there before.  Thus, it "erases" the old number by printing a new, longer number over the top of it.

Comment: `while true; do echo -en '\r <multiple spacebars>'; echo -en '\r'; wc -l file; sleep 1; done` no, seemingly not.

Comment: The wc -l prints a newline when it's done, which moves the cursor to the next line.  Try doing `echo -en "\r $( wc -l )"` instead (or replace the `wc -l` with `echo -n $(wc -l)`.  Wrapping the `wc -l` inside `$()` essentially eats the trailing newline.

Comment: +1, though to be absolutely correct, you should change `read` to `read -r` (since otherwise a backslash at the end of a line would mess with the counting). Incidentally, with a bit of work, this can be adapted to also show the latest line of output, which may be useful for some commands.

Comment: Is `echo ""` any different from a simple `echo`?

Comment: @gerrit, they're functionally the same; I just like to be explicit when I'm saying "a blank line." :)

Answer (score 7):

This is a rough idea but you could use the `pv` command to count the number of lines as they're going by and display that to the screen.  `pv` among it's many switches has a `-l` switch which counts each line as it goes through.

#### Example

Here I'm using a while loop to simulate some files from your SVN output.

```
$ for i in $(seq 100); do echo "file$i"; sleep 2; done | pv -l -c >/dev/null
   3 0:00:05 [0.99/s ] [      <=>
```

It will keep overwritting the output line like this:

```
  18 0:00:36 [   0/s ] [                                     <=>                                                                  ]

  24 0:00:47 [0.991/s ] [                                                <=>                                                      ]
```

Comment: I was unaware of pv.  Hooray for learning stuff!

Comment: @dannysauer - pv is worth spending some time learning, it allows anything that goes through a pipe to be gauged and displayed.

Comment: I installed it after I read the comment and have been playing with it.  Eighteen years using Linux, and there's still always new stuff to discover. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can run your command in background as a job and redirect its stdout (and stderr optionally) to a logfile: `command > logfile &` where `&` designates job (if stderr too, say `&>` instead of `>`).

Then you can use wordcount utility to count the number of lines in your logfile with `wc -l`.

To show the change of state in one dynamically changing line, you could use something like `while true; do echo -en '\r'; wc -l logfile; sleep 1; done`, but I can't force bash to draw `\r` carriage return to kill the contents of the previous line.

See this question, it's nearly a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388090/how-to-delete-and-replace-last-line-in-the-terminal-using-bash

Comment: But he wants a real-time display that keeps incrementing, which is not what wc does.

Comment: @kurtm eh, what he wants much more is not to get his screen flooded with results of `printf/print/echo` as suggested by danny. :) Of course, he could use `less`, but I suppose, he can afford to say `wc -l logfile` everytime he gets impatient. I think, playing with `ncurses` or clearing the screen is an overkill here.

Comment: Well, yes.  He doesn't want it flooded, but he wants to know progress, otherwise he could just use the --quiet.

Comment: @kurtm see update: can you help to debug my `echo -e 'r'` command? It should erase the previously printed contents of line, so that it dynamically changes, but I can't force it to do that :(

Comment: You want to also add the n option to echo which suppresses the trailing newline.

Comment: Right, already found that, but it still doesn't save the day :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10925/discussion-between-kurtm-and-bob)